# Is there an Attribute Table Feature limit?

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, limitations

I am copying a table with 11,000+ features but only about 700 show up on the QGIS attribute table. Is there a limit? how can I avoid this problem?

Comment: What is the source file of you table (e.g. shapefile/dbf, dbf, postgresql/postgis table, ...etc)?

Comment: Do you have a definition query set?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a lot of features, you better use a postgis database. It can store the whole world (at least that's what the Openstreetmap people do).

My local exctract holds over 900000 points, and QGIS has no problem showing the whole attribute table when zooming to the extent. You should disable rendering for that as that is the main blocker.